# JAVA ME: LWUIT Camera Video Component

Tags: java-me, camera, lwuit

I am using this line of code to start the Video Component:

```
videoComponent = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("capture://video");
```

The code I have works perfectly on a Nokia phone but I have another phone by OLG and this line always fails. Both "capture://video" and "capture://image" don't work.

Does anyone know how to find out whats the proper string to put there or all the possibilities?

I would search it but I don't know what to type into Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoComponent in LWUIT 1.5 had many bugs and since LWUIT is effectively abandoned it will probably never be fixed and never really worked well. With [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) we migrated to a more traditional Media approach, I would recommend migrating to Codename One.